# Nginx server .php files not processing thrown 404 error

Tags: php, nginx, centos7, fpm

My Nginx configuration file located in **default.conf** and my installed php version is: `PHP 7.1.14 (cli) (built: Jan 31 2018 08:35:35) ( NTS )`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

My index.php file location in:

```
/testPaymentPanel {
    alias /var/www/epayment/ ;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

**`systemctl`** status from php-fpm.service:

```
Active: active (running) since  2018-02-04 15:31:05 +0330; 13min ago
```

But when i open my URL which look likes 
 `https://www.example.com/testPaymentPanel/` Nginx returns **`404`**

And error log found with command `tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log/`

```
GET /testPaymentPanel/ HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
```

**`php-fpm`** server configs located in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf which below:

```
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
isten = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
```